# Why there was no power to an electric cloth dryer?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance

The other day I stumbled on something very puzzling to me.
I installed a 3 prong dryer cord on a previously working dryer and as I plugged it in the wall outlet the dryer would not turn on.
I was aware that the outlet was good.  I unplugged the cord and checked it for continuity on all three pins.  The continuity was perfect.

The fellow that I was doing this for said that the cord was bad and I assured him the cord was good based on the ohmmeter.

I had tossed that bad cord in my truck and was forgotten.

Months passed.  One fine day I checked the cord again when I found out that when it is bent just the right way, the return wire would show discontinuity.

Except the heating element, the rest of the dryer runs on 120V.

Comment: The resistance of the wire causing a high current drop at load would be an issue. Or breaks in the wire that while wouldn't stop a continuity meter would stop a multi amp machine from working. Length of the wire vs current, etc.

Comment: Further, cords can have an issue that is only observed when clamped or stressed. E.g. free cable - normal , clamped in appliance - break

Comment: What measurement tool was used, multimeter? Which brand and model? The meter probably wasn't revealing the truth of the situation.

Comment: Most problem happens at connector. Just had contact.

Comment: Every issue you brought up I have already accounted for all of it.  I kept my topic short to the point instead of a long narrative.  And thank you. Just to keep it brief again, I am not exactly a novice or lack basic understanding.  I am just hoping that I have missed something.  So far nothing different than what I already know.  Therefore anyone in my shoe will be scratching their head like myself.

Comment: From Passerby: "Or breaks in the wire that while wouldn't stop a continuity meter would stop a multi amp machine from working".  That was the only thing that had stuck in my mind's eye.  But I say to myself: " How much current it takes for LEDs on the user interface to come on.  Of course it is clear that only the heating element runs on the two legs of 240V... but that is another issue altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The continuity was perfect.

What, exactly, does this mean? If you used a meter with a continuity function, it only means that the resistance on each line was less than some preset limit - and this limit may have been well above what the dryer (which is a very high-current device) could allow.

Go back to your cable, and set your meter to Ohms on the lowest resistance scale. Touch the two probes together and record the resistance. Now check the resistance of each line in the suspect cable. It should be very, very close to zero.

> The fellow that I was doing this for said that the cord was bad

So, of course, when you told him it was good, you then asked him **why** he thought it was bad, right?

No? Why not? If he thought it was bad because he had tried it before, or on another piece of gear, and it didn't work then, why did you think it would work this time?

Comment: No need to get into the psychology of this.    Hey RoughBeast, the guy was janitor that didn't even make it through high school. Kapeesh?  I was hoping someone say something I have not accounted for. Ask yourself this question: How much current it takes for user interface LEDs to come on.

Comment: @Ali - Oh. You mean when you used the "bad" cord, the control LEDs came on but the dryer wouldn't start? You never mentioned that. And even if the guy is just a janitor, he presumably knows when a cord is bad if he's tried it and it didn't work. And you haven't answered my original question - what, exactly does "continuity was perfect" mean? How did you test it? On a continuity function? If so, what are the limits on that continuity function? If you mean that the end-to-end resistance of all lines was less than some number, you should say that - and mention the number.

Comment: I don't believe I said that anywhere. With the bad cord that passed resitance test, everything was dead.  The substitute old used up cord the dryer ran like grape ape.  Unfortunately for 10 seconds after I heard all the crap inside (lint, coins, paper clips and what not) coming out of the back vent.  Then the dryer died for good. even with brand new cord.  But none of this is the point obviously.  The point in the post is clear. Continuity being perfect means it was 0 ohms using Fluke  Is there a different perfect? So much for trying to avoid endless back and forth and get nowhere.

Comment: I was merely pointing that even with a bad cord ( a cord that is not severed), one should see some sort of life on the user interface even if I had my resistance measurement off by lots of ohms and just a terrible cluts of a person I maybe.  It appears to me you are not staying on target.  Just simply focus on the crux of what the post is saying.  If I told you the entire story with this, it will become anything but an electrical subject.

Comment: I was merely pointing to the statement of PasserBy, the cord needing enough integrity for multi-amp machine is not a satisfying reason.  That although it passes resistance test, it doesn't mean it can handle the amperage.  So I simply pointed clearly to his statement... "how much amperage it takes to light up a user interface?".    Say less than 500mA, far less that is. Such issues doesn't seem to enter as a matter of real subject to you, RoughBeast.  I have no desire to get technical here. I am not interested.

Comment: You might want to learn about smps power supply.  Just the main basic principle. I need to stop it here. Keep on going just tires me out. 45 years of experience in electrical engineering the guy on Quora, I told him to stop it. Perhaps either these folks just became regurgitators or imposters.  As when it comes to it, they know less than I care to use my fingers to push keyboard buttons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand the basics of an SMPS. I've got 35 years as an aerospace/electrical engineer with a Federally Funded Research and Development Center. I've launched a dozen suborbital missiles and a reconnaisance satellite -  and I understand that clothes dryers draw most of their power NOT through an SMPS. So where you got that issue, and why you think it's important, is completely beyond me.

Comment: What voltage and current is needed for user interface to light up, even if the system is linear supply and not smps?  User interface plays no bigger role than a computer keyboard basically.